# comparing bits to unsigned character arrays in C

Tags: c, openssl

I have a function that tests for partial collision in *sha256* hashing. After compiling to a file named `sha256`, a call in the terminally looks like this:

```
./sha256 2612c7
```

The function `sha256` repeatedly generate random bytes to a `unsigned char *` variable, lets just call it `buffer` in this case, and compare the first `k` bits to the argument given. The hash in `buffer` is generated by *OpenSSL*'s [EVP library](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Message_Digests).

In this case, the argument given is `2612c7`, and it exists in `argv[1]`. `k = 24`, because `2612c7` is 24 bits. I need to repeated compare the randomly hashed value in `buffer` to `argv[1]` and see if they're the same, which indicates collision in the first `k` bits.

---

I'm kind of confused as to what form `argv[1]` exist as? Or just how to compare this in general?

I wrote this function:

```
int match(unsigned char * buffer, unsigned char * hash_value) {
    int i = 0;

    while(hash_value[i] != '\0') {
        if(hash_value[i] != buffer[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

and I'm calling `match` with `match(buffer, (unsigned char *) argv[2])`, but no collision is being found even with extremely small `k` values (e.g. `./sha256 2`).

---

Here's the complete code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/random.h>

#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* utitlity function to help matching */
int match(unsigned char * md_value, unsigned char * hash_value) {
    int i = 0;

    while(hash_value[i] != '\0') {
        if(hash_value[i] != md_value[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 1;
}

/* ./this.o <digest method> <hash value> */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    /* hash function initiation */
    EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int md_len;

    /* seeding for random number generator */
    void *seed = NULL;
    int rseed;

    /* random generator initiation */
    unsigned char buffer[128];

    /* utility variables for counting */
    int i = 0;

    /* parameter checking */
    if (argv[2] == NULL) {
        printf("No hash value given\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        printf("No digest method given\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* get hash method */
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);
    if (md == NULL) {
        printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* random generator initialization */
    if(RAND_load_file("/dev/random", 32) != 32) {
        printf("random initialization failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    do {

        /* generate random text */
        if(RAND_bytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 1) {
            printf("failed generating random text");
            exit(1);
        } 

        /* hash the random text */
        mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
        EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
        EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
        EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);

        /* reseed random */
        rseed = syscall(SYS_getrandom, seed, (size_t) 128, (unsigned int) 1);
        RAND_seed(seed, rseed);

        i++;
    } while(match(md_value, (unsigned char *) argv[2]) == 0);

    printf("collision found: %d tries\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

note that the function in actuality is being called with `./a.out sha256 2612c7`, I simplified the example above for simplicity.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are incrementing `i` in the `match()` function.

Comment: How exactly is `buffer` populated?  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to write that down, `i` isn't the problem @David Bowling

Comment: @dbush the link I provided gives a complete example

Comment: A good reason to include a [mcve] for us to work from....

Comment: @thestateofmay The OpenSSL example doesn't help us.  We need to see the code **you wrote**, copy and pasted verbatim into the question (not retyped), to know what you did wrong.

Comment: I updated my complete code.